# Removal Company Behavior - Is it a scam?

Tags: united-kingdom, scams, france, moving

I have just relocated from the Uk to France, and I have agreed with company A to make the removal of all the items in my house for around 5,000 £ (a good price, but not too good to be true in my opinion). However, company A is a local company that does not make international removal, so they said they would have passed all my items to another company in England (company B) to complete the removal (a company they completely trust).

Company A has received 3,200 £ for their job, and the other one should have received directly from me 750 £ as deposit, and another 1,000 on the day the items were delivered to me in France.

We have already used company A a few years ago for a removal of about 700 £ in nearby cities, and everything was fine. However, this time their behavior has made me suspicious. They were very friendly and kind until I paid the 3,200 £, which I did when the job was done, but not completed yet. So, I basically ended getting the things that were left around the house myself and bringing them to their van, because they were clearly trying to go away as quickly as possible without caring about the things that were left. We also had a small argument because their behavior was not acceptable for me.

In any case, the next day I paid the 750 £ to the other company, they thanked me and asked me to pay the whole amount in full before the delivery (3 days in advance to be precise). I refused, because that was not what we agreed. He accepted it, but said that he would have collected the money before unloading his van on his arrival, and I said it was fine.

Today, just one day before the goods have to be delivered, he phoned me and told me that his big van had a fault, and he cannot deliver all my stuff, but that he will deliver only part of them tomorrow (since a smaller van has reached him and he has loaded it with what he could), and the rest in the future (possibly at the end of the week).

They have a website, and positive reviews on facebook, the removal was essentially arranged by company A, and we have all the various emails that we exchanged between them. I did notice that company A sent his quote as if his job was the removal of my stuff and the delivery of them to company B and not to france.

Is it a scam? What can I do to protected my money and my things? Should I refuse to pay the 1000 £, pay only a part of it, or call the French police and possibly the UK one?

Comment: I don't know about scam, but sounds like a typical mover shakedown horror story. I guess it depends on whether the rest of your stuff arrives in a few days.

Comment: Do you have a contract with either company? What does the contract say? Is there any insurance? Is there any regulatory oversight or license required for their services?

Comment: It sounds a lot like they're almost bankrupt and want to collect as much money as possible before failing completely